# Auto filter based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to do an auto filter based on cell value, I got the code to work for the most part but I still stuck on 2 things

1. I want it to be a partial match (currently it is full match)
2. I want it to be none case sensitive (currently it is case sensitive)
   How do I modify the code?

Q2 in the code refer to column header and Q3 refer to the actual value (name)
Thank you in advance for your help!

```
    Sub Filter()
    Dim FNameVal As String
    Dim cell As Range

    With Sheets("Database")
        FNameVal = .Range("Q3").Value2
        For Each cell In .Range("B6:U1000").Cells
            If FNameVal = cell.Value2 Then
                Range("B6:U1000").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("Q2:Q3")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the value in `Q3` and also an example of a string you want to partial match on?

Comment: Q3 for exmaple, mm and full name on the list Emma

Comment: Are the headers in row `6`? Is column `V` empty?

Answer (score 0):

### Filter a Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub filterRange()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
        Dim cel As Range: Set cel = .Range("B6")
        Dim rg As Range
        With cel.CurrentRegion
            Set rg = cel.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count - cel.Row, _
                .Column + .Columns.Count - cel.Column)
        End With
        'Debug.Print rg.Address
        Dim Header As String: Header = CStr(.Range("Q2").Value)
        Dim cIndex As Variant
        cIndex = Application.Match(Header, rg.Rows(1), 0)
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            Dim Criteria As String
            Criteria = "*" & CStr(.Range("Q3").Value) & "*"
            rg.AutoFilter cIndex, Criteria
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Else
            MsgBox "The range '" & rg.Address(0, 0) & "' does not contain " _
                & "the header '" & Header & "'.", vbExclamation, _
                "Header Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```